# Declaring refrences /objects in Destructor of a class

Tags: c++, destructor

Does it make any sense of declaring objects or refrences in a destructor of a class in C++?

I mean

```
class A
{
   A()
   {
   }

  ~A()
   {
      //Declaring refrences or objects  here //
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need local variables in your dtor, then use them.  There is no special restriction; the body of a dtor is treated like the body of any function.  If you don't need them, then it wouldn't make sense to declare them.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare any type of variable if you need it, but you should delete it properly like in the other cases. what is the case?